# Windows 11 Single monitor scaling

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-11

On Windows 10 I could easily swap the scaling/zoom per monitor by selecting the selected monitor and adjusting this value.

On Windows 11 I can not seem to find this option and only what they call scaling which scales all monitors to the same size and the "automatic scaling" does not give me the view I want.

The desired outcome is
Monitor 1 175% (2496x1664)
Monitor 2 125% (1920x1080)
Monitor 3 125% (1920x1080)

**Windows 10 Monitor 1 (Example)**

[image]

**Windows 10 Monitor 2 (Example)**

[image]

**Windows 11**
[image]

Warning of changing all monitors instead of single

[image]

Comment: Have you tried "turn off custom scaling and sign out"?  Are you connected to an Active Directory by chance?

Comment: @Ramhound, Yeah that will result in putting the screens at 200% and 100%

Comment: Just to be clear, does this not work? https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-set-different-display-scaling-level-for-multiple-monitors-in-windows-10

Comment: Can you tell us more about the display and indicate if you are or aren’t connected to a AD domain?

Answer (score 3):

You are doing it wrong. You don't need to set a custom scale.

step 1: click on turn off custom scaling and sign out.
[Turn off custom scaling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYGIV.png)

step 2: Next time go to settings > system > display.
From the window where you can arrange your screens,
click on the display you want to set scaling.

on Scale & layout section, **DO NOT click on the arrow (>)**.
Just click on the percentage shown. for example if its showing 100% (Recommended) click on it
That will give you option to change scaling.
You have options for 100%, 125%, 150%, and 175%
select what you want. do the same for other screens also.

Comment: Surprisingly, this works and does indeed let you define different scaling levels per monitor. Such a confusing, strange UI on Microsoft's part.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering here as I cannot comment. If you want 175% scaling and 125% scaling there's no need to use custom scaling to try turning off this feature and see if you are able to set different scaling between monitors (as Custom Scaling feature sets it across all monitors).

Please check out this [link](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/change-display-dpi-scaling-level-in-windows-11.934/) for better understanding.

I think you should try: canceling custom scaling and putting a different scale of each monitor (I saw in comments what it will result, no worries it is good for us). Now open Registry (press Windows key + R and write `regedit`), in there enter in the top bar `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\PerMonitorSettings`. In `PerMonitorSettings` folder you'll have each monitor scaling settings. Press on the folder named by the monitor you want it's scaling to be 125% and in DpiValue set in Hexadecimal the value 1, in the folder named after the monitor you want it's scale to be set 175% change DpiValue to 3 in Hexadecimal. Now just restart/sign out and you are all set!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Link-only answers are not helpful. You should quote and cite the relevant information from your link.  Commentary about being unable to submit a comment should be removed from answers.

Comment: If you read you see it's not a link only. I explained how to solve this and attached a link if he wants to read further more.

Comment: @Ramhound I elaborated more for an easier understanding. Shame though that someone is just trying to help and he gets down voted, I would never understand that..

Comment: @SQLTemp please check the instructions I added in the recent edit of my answer. I believe this would solve the problem for you (I tested it and it worked).

Comment: @WillingMost7 down votes were earned. First, many people who aren't trying to answer begin their posts with "I can't comment so I'm..." and post something that is not an answer in the Answers section. There's a reason there are reputation barriers to interaction here. Good reasons. Yours was an attempt to answer, but when you first posted, it was a poor one, because...

Comment: Second, the rules aren't exactly hard to find on this site, and low rep users are walked through them pretty clearly, and one of these is that all of the answer's info should be here, in this page. Links are for attribution and research. You've done well improving this answer. It's a good answer now. Post more like this and you'll quickly earn the rep to interact more fully.

Comment: @WillingMost7 - [This](https://superuser.com/revisions/1729391/1) was nothing more than what could be easily described as a sign post. Without the link it didn’t answer the author’s question.